# .NET ASPX project changes not appearing on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, tfs

I have been working on a .net aspx (c#) project for a client of mine (I inherited it in it's current state from a previous developer).

I have been making front end and 'code behind' changes as well as database stuff with no problem until today.

The project is being built using Visual Studio, with code being checked into TFS (team foundation server) - and the site is deployed to Microsoft Azure hosted server - the build server is also hosted by Microsoft, and to date all i've been doing is hitting 'build', choosing the build name and letting it get on with it - a couple of minutes later i can refresh the site in a browser and my changes appear - nice.

However I've come unstuck - I'm trying to edit Login.aspx and RecoverPassword.aspx which reside in a folder called /account - I believe they were originally automatically generated files which have been edited and changed - I want to do some minor editing on them - I can change them, hit F5 and test locally on http://localhost/ - however the changes just are not appearing on azure/live website.

The files in question (.aspx) were set to Build: Compile - i have also tried setting it to 'Content' with no luck.

It's as though the build is ignoring these files or rejecting the changes - I'm lost - I've tested that it's not Microsoft's fault by making changes to other files and building - the build completes and changes are made - seemingly it's just these two files.

Within the /Account directory:
- Login.aspx
- RecoveryPassword.aspx
- Web.config

Web.config contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="recoverpassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

I would like to add that in Visual Studio the files appear greyed out and say latest: not downloaded, last checkin 1/12/2012

I suspect this could be a file permissions problem, will keep digging!

Answer (score 1):

Did two things to resolve this:

1. Re-mapped the folder within Visual studio to a new folder on my desktop and ran a 'get' to get the latest version of code within this folder (account folder)
2. Had the project owner set me as 'Project administrator' and then assign this security permission to the folders in question

Hope this helps someone in future